# Can't change x axis format SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2014

I'm trying to change the x axis format that now for ex. looks like this 201601012300 by right click on the x axic prop, number and choose the format (I try different formats). Strangely but it's not working. Just to be sure, when i change the font, it's responding that how i Know that i select the wright axis prop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try with Expression and force the display format like this : 
=Format(Fields!MyDate.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: Just to be sure, the type of x axis values is DateTime ?

Comment: I'm taking this member: WITH MEMBER MEASURES.TheDate AS [Dim Time Online].[Date Key].currentmember.name.  I'm not very strong at SSAS. Is this a date format?

Comment: I think you have a string value because you return the current member name, not the value.. 
Did you try (without .name): 

WITH MEMBER MEASURES.TheDate AS [Dim Time Online].[Date Key].currentmember

Comment: Now i change it to CURRENTMEMBER.member_value and it still not working. By the way,  when i change at axis options to scalar axis it starting to react. but still not giving me the right format

Comment: Having a string value to convert in DateTime format is a little laborious in SSRS but with your exemple "201601012300", I have "01/01/2016 23:00" with this expression :
=format(
      CDate(
          Mid(Fields!Day.Value,5,2)
             & "/"
             & Mid(Fields!Day.Value,7,2)
             & "/"
             & Left(Fields!Day.Value,4)
             & " "
             & Mid(Fields!Day.Value,9,2)
             & ":"
             & Right(Fields!Day.Value,2)
             & ":00"),
          "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")

Comment: unfortunatly It disrupts the data: instead 201602152300 i'm geting : 2016021522/15/2316 23:00

Comment: Mid(value, 5, 2) return more than 2 characters ?.. Very weird ! Can you show me your expression please ?

Comment: Yes, this very wierd. This is the expression without time:   =Mid(Fields!TheDate.Value,5,2) & "/" & Mid(Fields!TheDate.Value,7,2) & "/" & Left(Fields!TheDate.Value,4)

Comment: I tried your expression in my own report and it works fine.. :(
With a string "201602152300", I have : 02/15/2016

Comment: What is the result if you put only =Mid(Fields!TheDate.Value,5,2) in the expression ?

Comment: The resault is: 2016021523002. I assume that the issue is with the variable of MDX 'cous always give the default string 201602152300 and the cur part

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused because your date field is not in the date format. I had this exact issue and this resolved it.